# how to call columns/row in python

Tags: python

I need to call/retrieve some specific columns in a row of a dataset using the number (not the names of the columns). what is the best way to do this? My code is:

```
with open('collected_quotes_total_chunk2.csv', 'rb') as quote_sample:
        quote_database = csv.DictReader(quote_sample)
        to_db = [(row['#RIC'], row['Date[L]'], row['Time[L]'], row['before_or_after']) for row in quote_database]
```

So instead of names, I want to use column number e.g. 2,3,5,6,7,9,14

Thanks heaps guys

Comment: you are using the csv library correct, if yes, not sure you can do that, there are more suitable ones for this such as pandas

Answer (score 0):

Use a [reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader), instead of [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), to read the row as an array.